# How to add filtering for function based views in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add filters to my function-based views. Using Class Based Views I was able to add filters to views. But I'm curious if I can add filtering to this function based views. I need to filter subject by it's name through a web search. How I can achieve that

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def TeacherSubject(request):
    teacher = TeacherProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    subject = Subject.objects.filter(author=teacher).order_by('-id')
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 5
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(subject, request)
    serializer = SubjectSerializer(result_page,many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/). For example

```
# filters.py

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price', 'release_date']

# views.py
...
from .filters import ProductFilter


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def product_list(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filterset = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    if filterset.is_valid():
         queryset = filterset.qs
    serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you need raise Validation errors, use this

```
from .filters import ProductFilter
from django_filters.utils import translate_validation

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def product_list(request):
    filterset = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    if not filterset.is_valid():
         raise translate_validation(filterset.errors)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(filterset.qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Pagination

```
from .filters import ProductFilter
from django_filters.utils import translate_validation
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def product_list(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 5
    
    filterset = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    if not filterset.is_valid():
         raise translate_validation(filterset.errors)

    queryset = paginator.paginate_queryset(filterset.qs, request)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: `@api_view(['GET'])
def SubjectList(request):
    subjects = SubjectFilter ( request.GET, queryset= Subject.objects.all())
    serializer = SubjectViewSerializer(subjects,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)` after triggering the API it gives 'SubjectFilter' object is not iterable

Comment: yep, you right. I'm updating answer. Check now.

Comment: Yeah, It's working now but without the pagination. with the pagination, it gives me all the results in the response

Comment: You are somehow not setting pagination correctly. Updated answer